# Building multiple maven artifacts across a range of dependencies

Tags: java, maven, build

Is there a way with Maven to build and test a project multiple times across a range of dependency versions?

For instance,  Say I have the following Libraries:

```
groupId        artifactId  version
com.example    library     1.0
com.example    library     1.1
com.example    library     2.0
com.example    library     2.2
```

And my build produces a jar artifact: output.jar

Could I produce the following against each of the library versions:

```
groupId        artifactId  version    result
com.example    library     1.0        output_1.0.jar
com.example    library     1.1        output_1.1.jar
com.example    library     2.0        output_2.0.jar
com.example    library     2.2        output_2.2.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try profiles http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>version1.0</id>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>library</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-library-1.0.jar</finalName>
    </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>version1.1</id>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.example</groupId>
         <artifactId>library</artifactId>
         <version>1.1</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}-library-1.1.jar</finalName>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then when you call maven,:  mvn -Pversion1.1

One of your profiles should probably be active by default so that you can compile without having a specific profile enabled.

```
<activation>
  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

Comment: ps:  this will not build it multiple times as you would have to call maven for each different profile to test the compile.   Either create a shell/batch script to do that, or if you're using build software (jenkins, et all...) just have that do it.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks. Too bad I cant specify a range of dependencies, that would have been really slick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the matrix project feature of jenkins or hudson. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project

> A multi-configuration project is useful for instances where your builds will make many similar build steps, and you would otherwise be duplicating steps.

But you can't build the project on you local machine that way.

Comment: This may work nicely with the Maven profiles in the answer by Matt.  I'll give it a shot.